# MySQL JOIN on an arbitrary number of tables with independent WHERE clauses

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

I'm building a complex search application with a large number of potential inputs. Each input is optional. I'm trying to build a query in a modular fashion.

Let's say I have two distinct queries, each with independent `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.c1 = x

SELECT * FROM t2 WHERE t2.c1 = y
```

I've found the following code to be valid:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c2 = t2.c2 WHERE t1.c1= x AND t2.c1= y
```

However, since the `WHERE` conditions are grouped together at the end, it would be very difficult to implement this in a modular fashion. So, I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE t1.c1 = x INNER JOIN ON t1.c2 = t2.c2 WHERE t2.c1 = y
```

However, this code is invalid. What's the best way to join an arbitrary number of tables with independent `WHERE` clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joins between the tables may be able to be implemented conditionally -- and the `where` clauses concatenated at the end -- like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM t1 
  INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.c2 = t2.c2 
  INNER JOIN t3 ON t1.c3 = t3.c3  
  INNER JOIN t4 ON t1.c4 = t4.c4  
WHERE t1.c1 = x 
  AND t2.c2 = y
  AND t3.c3 = z
  AND t4.c4 = a
```

And you can build this as a string conditionally depending on which options the user chooses.

While building the `where` clauses and the `joins` together dynamically may work, there may be some pitfalls to watch out for.

First, the joins will still likely have to be custom built based on the the natural way the tables join together -- for example, `t3` may only be joinable to `t2` and not `t1`. You'll have similar issues with the `where` clauses. Each where clause will have to be custom built depending on the columns in the table.

In other words, it's unlikely that this problem is completely generalizable. In the end you'll need to craft custom SQL that will depend on the specifics of the tables. Worse yet, over time the tables will change and the SQL will have to change with it. If you are building complicated SQL dynamically, you may be setting yourself up for a maintenance headache.

Moreover, as your app grows you'll likely want to tune the SQL for each combination to optimize the queries. Make sure you try to take this into account as you build this out.

Comment: Useful stuff. For now, I'll build the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses in parallel. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation, I dynamically build the WHERE clause in code.  I'm not sure that there is a better approach.

Be sure to use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-net-programming-prepared.html) (parameterized queries).  Building a WHERE clause without parameters is a [huge security issue](http://xkcd.com/327/).